# session never destroy for application in any browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-timeout

Here is the story of me creating a web application using **ASP.NET 4.5** with **EntityFramework**. I use **ASP.NET control** for login and logout functionalities. Now, my issue is that I want to create such application in which I need user to be always logged in to the application after closing the browser or system as a **Gmail** account.

I tried searching on net but didn't get any proper results. How I can implement this by using session for any browser?

Answer (score 0):

Session is the term derived one instance of the browser, means till the browser gets closed.
To have user session even if browser gets closed, create a cookie.

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("cookieUser");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

// Set the cookie value.
myCookie.Value = now.ToString();
// Set the cookie expiration date.
myCookie.Expires = now.AddMinutes(10);

// Add the cookie.
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Gmail also works in the same way.
Remember me at this computer explicitly saves the cookie

Hope this helps.